# Firestore query onSnapshot is returning me all previous docs on each change

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am adding docs to a collection of messages. For getting real time updates in my UI, I am listening to new docs that have been created after "new Date()".

The thing is that, after getting the first snapshot with all the documents that match the query, when a new doc is added, I am receiving all the previous detected docs in the listener.

Is this the expected behavior?? What am I doing wrong?

This is what I am doing:

```js
    export function listenNonDeletedChatMessages(
      chatRoomId,
      startAt = undefined,
      onMessageReceived = undefined,
      onNext = undefined,
      onError = undefined
    ) {
      const currentUser = getCurrentUser();
    
      if (!currentUser) {
        throw authErrors.authenticationRequired();
      }
    
      let query = firestore
        .collection("chats")
        .doc(chatRoomId)
        .collection("messages")
        .where("content.deletedAt", "==", null)
        .orderBy("date");
    
      if (startAt) {
        query = query.startAt(startAt);
      }
    
      return query.onSnapshot(handleChanges, onError);
    
      function handleChanges(querySnapshot) {
        const messages = [];
    
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => { // I am getting N docs on each change, why? 
          const messageData = {
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data(),
          };
    
          const parsedMessage = parseChatMessage(
            messageData,
            currentUser.uid
          );
    
          console.log(messageData); <--- this method is logging me all the already detected docs!
    
          messages.unshift(parsedMessage);
    
          onMessageReceived?.(parsedMessage);
        });
    
        querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => { // 1 change detected, as expected
          console.log(change.type); <--- THIS ONLY LOGS "added" one time when a doc is added!
        });
    
        onNext?.(messages);
      }
    }
```

Note: I am not talking about the initial status, where all docs are fetched, I am saying that I am receving the same docs again and again on any new doc addition, while they are not being modified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the expected behavior: the `QuerySnapshot` contains information about all documents that match the query, not just about the changes.

If you want to process all documents, loop over `docs` as you do first in your code.

If you want to process only the changes, loop over `docChanges` as you do later in your code.

Comment: If I loop using docChanges, would I be rereading the N documents that match the query every time the listener detects a change (only one change)?

Comment: If you keep the listener active, it'll only retrieve the changes from the server - regardless of which property of the snapshot you access.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Frank Solution, in order to avoid getting same docs of the query, doing something like this will work:

```
export function listenNonDeletedChatMessages(
  chatRoomId,
  startAt = undefined,
  onMessageReceived = undefined,
  onNext = undefined,
  onError = undefined
) {
  const currentUser = getCurrentUser();

  if (!currentUser) {
    throw authErrors.authenticationRequired();
  }

  let query = firestore
    .collection("chats")
    .doc(chatRoomId)
    .collection("messages")
    .where("content.deletedAt", "==", null)
    .orderBy("date");

  if (startAt) {
    query = query.startAt(startAt);
  }

  return query.onSnapshot(handleChanges, onError);

  function handleChanges(querySnapshot) {
    const messages = [];

    querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
      if (change.type === "added") {
        const messageData = {
          id: change.doc.id,
          ...change.doc.data(),
        };

        const parsedMessage = parseChatMessage(
          messageData,
          currentUser.uid
        );

        messages.unshift(parsedMessage);

        onMessageReceived?.(parsedMessage);
      };
    });

    onNext?.(messages);
  }
}
```